# IE border-radius - specific part still square, despite (seemingly) valid CSS rule

Tags: internet-explorer-9, css

I have been having problems with one div, the header of my site, which has the rule:

```
div#header {
width:100%;
background-color:#660066;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#330033), to(#990099), color-stop(.5,#660066));
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #330033 0%, #660066 50%, #990099 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#330033', endColorstr='#990099',GradientType=0 );
-moz-border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
border-radius:15px 15px 0px 0px;
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 0px 3px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 0px 3x #888;
box-shadow: 3px 0px 3px #888;
}
```

Yet in IE9 the top left and right is not rounded. In Chrome, Safari and Firefox they are.

[See it here](http://www.crgsshare.tk/) (the header div contains the logo and the "CRGS Share
Student File Sharing System" title)

Do you know what could be the cause? It's probably just me being a noob.

[Full stylesheet here](http://www.crgsshare.tk/styles.css) (it's messy as it's a bit of a work in progress).

Cheers in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in IE 9. It supports round borders as well as gradients but not both of them at the same time. This means that if you want the gradients, IE 9 will show that but will ignore the round corners. Alternatively what you can do however is that create a gradient image and use that for the browsers that don't understand gradients. Example:

```
div#header {
width:100%;
border:0px;
background-color:#660066;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#330033), to(#990099), color-stop(.5,#660066));
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #330033 0%, #660066 50%, #990099 100%);
background-image: url('your gradient image.png') 0 0 repeat;
-moz-border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
border-radius:15px 15px 0px 0px;
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 0px 3px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 0px 3x #888;
box-shadow: 3px 0px 3px #888;
}
```

Comment: Oh I see! Well, to be honest it does not make a huge deal of difference, I might make an image later on when I get more IE9 visitors. Thanks a lot mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Gradient will go out for rounded corners in IE9, so the best solution for now to add one extra div:

```
 <div class="corners"><div class="gradient"></div></div>
```

and hide overflow for .corners

```
.corners {
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;

overflow: hidden;
}
```

I recomend this Photoshop-like tool for creating cross-browser gradients: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

And this one to create border-radius:
http://border-radius.com/